# Hyperwallet service working in postmant, but not working in c# code with http request.?

Tags: c#

```
I am using **hyper wallet payment api** in one of my application.  

An api of hyper wallet working Postman but not working with c# httpwebrequest calling.
```

> It is giving forbidden 403 error after service calling.

```
Thank you  


               var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));
                string authInfo = "username" + ":" + "123456";
                http.Method = "POST";
                //http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "123456");
                http.ContentType = "application/json";
                http.Accept = "application/json";
                http.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
                http.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic cmVzdGFwaXVzZXJAMTU1NDM3OTE2MTg6a2Fuc29mdEAxMjM=";
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

                //string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
                Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                newStream.Close();
                var response = http.GetResponse();
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return content;
```

Why this code giving 403 forbidden error. But still working in postman..?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide us with your code? I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: Try taking a screenshot of your postman and the headers/request body (if POST) I think that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks to all, My issue has been resolved. I was doing a silly mistake in my input model. But now it has been resoved.  Thanks